# Custom binding stopped working after routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a `home` component and the default `app` component.

In the `AppComponent` class, I have an object named `ninjaApp` and a method named `yell()` .

I want to show `ninjaApp`'s attributes and call `yell()` in the `home` component. (custom property and event binding).

It was working well untill I added routing.

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() ninjaApp;
  @Output() onYell = new EventEmitter();

  propertyBindingEx1 = "property binding ex1";
  propertyBindingEx2 = "property binding ex2";
  ninja = {
    name: "josh",
    belt: "black"
  };

  eventB(myVal) {
    alert(myVal);
  };

  fireYellEvent(e) {
    this.onYell.emit(e);
  };


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**home.component.html:**

```
<p>
  home works!
</p>

<ng-content></ng-content>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Property binding -->

<input value="{{propertyBindingEx1}}">
<input [value]="propertyBindingEx2">

<!-- Event binding -->

<button (click)="eventB('go go go event binding')"> Event binding! </button>

<!-- 2-way data binding -->

<br><br><br>
<input [(ngModel)]= "ninja.belt">

<p>{{ninja.name}}</p> <!-- this is property binding -->
<p>{{ninja.belt}}</p>

<p>{{ninjaApp.name}}</p> <!-- Custom property binding -->
<button (click)="fireYellEvent($event)">Make me Yell</button> <!-- Custom event binding -->
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works! yahhhhhhhooooo';

  ninjaApp = {
    name: "ruy",
    belt: "red"
  };

  yell(e){
    alert("I am Yelling!")
  };

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<!--
<app-home [ninjaApp]="ninjaApp" (onYell)="yell($event)"> this is some info to be shown later as ng-content </app-home>
-->

<router-outlet ></router-outlet>
```

and this is the routing file, **app.routes.ts**:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { DirectoryComponent } from "./directory/directory.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";


const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'directory',
  component: DirectoryComponent,
 },
 { path: '',
  component: HomeComponent
 },
];

export const APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

and finally, **app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DirectoryComponent } from './directory/directory.component';

import {APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER} from "./app.routes";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DirectoryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    APP_ROUTES_PROVIDER
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Console shows this error:**

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:25:3 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Error: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:25:3 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, your root route (`path: '',
  component: HomeComponent`) displays the home component, and its template tries to display `ninjaApp.name`, but ninjaApp is never initialized, so it's undefined. You can't read a property of undefined.

Comment: in your app.routes.ts you go to `HomeComponent`. I think you meant `AppComponent`! because when you go to `HomeComponent` your inputs will not be defined !

Comment: Thank you, but just changing the path to `AppComponent` doesn't make it work, I am confused how to initialize `ninjaApp`

Comment: Inputs and outputs are useful to get data from, or emit events to, a parent component. If you use the home component as a route component, it dodn' have any parent component, so inputs and outputs don't make sense.

Comment: So `AppComponent` isn't a parent of all components including route components?

Comment: what happens if you put *ngIf="ninja" in home.component.html, before accessing data?